Определенные атрибуты в списке товаров WooCommerce
В интернет-магазине на WooCommerce я использую код, который выводит определенные атрибуты товаров на страницах архива/категорий.
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );
function new_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    $attrs_by_cats = [
        20 => [ 'pa_size' ],

    ];

    $attr_list = [
        'Размер'        => 'pa_size',
    ];

    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    $cats = $product->get_category_ids();

    if ( ! is_array( $cats ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $attrs = [];

    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        if ( isset( $attrs_by_cats[ $cat ] ) ) {
            $attrs[] = $attrs_by_cats[ $cat ];
        }
    }

    $allowed_attrs = array_unique( array_merge( [], ...$attrs ) );

    echo '<div class="">';

    foreach ( $attr_list as $attr_title => $attr_name ) {
        if ( in_array( $attr_name, $allowed_attrs, true ) ) {
            show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name );
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
function show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name ) {
    if ( 'sku' === $attr_name ) {
        $attr = (string) $product->get_sku();
    } else {
        $attr = $product->get_attribute( $attr_name );
    }

    if ( '' === $attr ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<span class="">' . esc_html( $attr ) . '</span>';
}

В данный момент, код выводит атрибут "Размер" одним списком/массивом, через запятую. Я же хотел бы показать размеры по отдельности и без запятой, т.е. каждый из размеров обернуть в span, а не все вместе.
Как это можно реализовать? Буду рад помощи с кодом!

Для того чтобы вывести каждый размер по отдельности и обернуть его в , вам нужно изменить функцию show_attribute. Вместо вывода всех значений атрибута через запятую, нужно разделить их и вывести каждое значение в отдельном .
Вот пример, как это может работать:


add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );
function new_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    $attrs_by_cats = [
        20 => [ 'pa_size' ],
    ];

    $attr_list = [
        'Размер'        => 'pa_size',
    ];

    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    $cats = $product->get_category_ids();

    if ( ! is_array( $cats ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $attrs = [];

    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        if ( isset( $attrs_by_cats[ $cat ] ) ) {
            $attrs[] = $attrs_by_cats[ $cat ];
        }
    }

    $allowed_attrs = array_unique( array_merge( [], ...$attrs ) );

    echo '<div class="">';

    foreach ( $attr_list as $attr_title => $attr_name ) {
        if ( in_array( $attr_name, $allowed_attrs, true ) ) {
            show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name );
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

function show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name ) {
    if ( 'sku' === $attr_name ) {
        $attr = (string) $product->get_sku();
    } else {
        $attr = $product->get_attribute( $attr_name );
    }

    if ( '' === $attr ) {
        return;
    }

    // Разделяем значения атрибута и выводим каждое в отдельном <span>
    $attr_values = explode( ', ', $attr );
    foreach ( $attr_values as $value ) {
        echo '<span class="">' . esc_html( $value ) . '</span>';
    }
}




Большое спасибо за вашу помощь.
